# Can't log in into Django admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I did look up the other people having a similar problem, but mine is slightly different.

When I try to log in the Django admin panel, my credentials (which are correct) don't work: I'm told I have to enter the right ones, that it might be case-sensitive, etc.

This occured first on a project where I fiddled with custom user/superusers and did terrible things to migrations, so I understood the root of the problem.

Now, the *real* problem is that when I switched back to another (fully working) project and tried to log into the admin console, I still had (and have) this bug even though

a) it worked before and I haven't touched the code since (a week ago)

b) I'm using Django's user model for this project.

I tried clearing my cookies, reinstalling Django and restarting my computer, but nothing's working. Both projects are fully independant; the only common point they have is django + being hosted on a SQlite local server.

For Project 2, I haven't touched either AUTH_USER_MODEL or AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS.

For Project 1, I have registered a user with AUTH_USER_MODEL but haven't touched AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS. I'm not interested in debugging Project 1's user model: *my problem is that Project 2 is also dysfunctioning now, even though its code was untouched*.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please visit the [help] and read [ask]. Your question lacks important debugging details (and includes some irrelevant ones). Please share the relevant settings (`AUTH_USER_MODEL`, `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`, etc.), how you registered the user and your custom user models code if you use any. If you have multiple projects just mention the _one in which you have the problem_.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat The problem is that I have the same problem in the two involved projects even though the code is wildly different in both.

Comment: That should not be relevant to your question / problem, unless you went and did things like modifying your local copy of the Django package itself (In case you don't use virtual environments for your project).

Comment: I didn't touch my local copy of Django, though I'm not using a virtual environment.

My question/problem is literally that I broke Project 1 and now Project 2 is broken too, so I don't understand how it's not relevant?

Comment: Both are using the same DB? Have you tried dropping and recreating it?

Comment: @Iain Shelvington No, both are using different DB (and are set in different folders).

Answer (score 0):

**You might be problem with the make password. This is just an example**

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

USER_PASSWORD = "abc123"

User.objects.create(first_name="hellow", last_name = faker.last_name(), username="helloworld", password = make_password(USER_PASSWORD), email ="hello@world.com")
```